# Access from one VM to an Other

Tags: macos, vmware-fusion

I got a Linux VM Image from a dev in our company to develop on it. This works nice, but now i need to do some Internet Explorer testing, for that i have an other VM with windows on it.

I have an entry in my hosts file under macos that redirect some virtual domain to the IP of the linux VM.

I tried to modify the hosts file in windows also. But i cant reach Linux VM.

How can i access the Server on the linux VM with Windows VM? Are there some settings i missed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that if you set both VMs to run as NAT'ed rather than bridged, they should end up within the same virtual network.  You can then assign them IP addresses rather than using DHCP and simply point the browser on one to the IP address of the other.

Answer (score 0):

Recently, I successfully accessed one VMware (running Linux with Jira) via HTTP from within another VMware (running Windows 7).

So I think it is working successfully. I used WMware Workstation on Windows 7 as the host operation system.

I doubt that it does behave differently on other hosts like OS X.

Maybe it is a firewall setting issue in the guest VMwares and/or a routing issue in the networks that the host provides to the guests?

Comment: did you have to do something special? I dont think that it has something to to with any firewall... I seams no to be in the same virtual network.

Comment: Well, both machines were configured to use our central DHCP server and the networks are set to "Bridged". I think if I had other settings (especially no DHCP server), thinks would have been more complicated.

Comment: our clients a strictly resticted on the network. I cant get more then one IP :/ I need to get from one LOCAL vm to an other LOCAL vm